# Qmail - Change maximum retry time

Tags: plesk, qmail

Hello I am running Plesk 10.4.4 with Qmail and noticed that one of my customers was spammed with an invalid address to which qmail kept trying to reply to. This unfortunately caused a major pile up (over 100 emails) in the system with some retries being held up for over 7 days and any new emails trying to go out would take up to 2 hours even if the addresses are correct.

Is there any way to tell qmail to not keep retrying and delete anything from queue that is over 2 hours old?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "7200" > /var/qmail/control/queuelifetime
/etc/init.d/qmail restart
```

7200 - it's 2 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds

But I think that 2 hours may be not enough, 1 or 2 days is OK for me.

Comment: I was thinking that as well. How could I see what it is currently set at?

Comment: By default /var/qmail/control/queuelifetime file doesn't exists. But default queue life time is 7 days.